# Better way to extract data from list of different splits in R

Tags: r

I want to extract the **test** data series from 10 splits using the time series CV. Currently, I am doing as given below. I am looking for an efficient way to do so.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(modeltime)
library(modeltime.resample)
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)

resamples_tscv <- time_series_cv(
  data        = m750,
  assess      = 6,
  initial     = 200,
  skip        = 1,
  slice_limit = 10
)

resamples_tscv
```

[image]

```
t1 <- testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[1]])
t2 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[2]])
t3 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[3]])
t4 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[4]])
t5 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[5]])
t6 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[6]])
t7 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[7]])
t8 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[8]])
t9 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[9]])
t10 <-testing(resamples_tscv$splits[[10]])

df <- do.call("rbind", list(t1, t2, t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10))
df1 <- df[order(as.Date(df$date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]
```

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, (lapply(resamples_tsv, function(i) testing(i$splits))))`

Comment: I am getting an error Error: `x` should be an `rsplit` object